# jQuery Datatables: Adding Additional column

Tags: jquery, datatables

Is it possible to show an additional column based on search criterion?For example, consider the following example from the following URL.

http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/multi_col_sort.html

Please find the Image below [image]

If a user searches for letter A under the CSS grade column, it should not only display all the letter A related rows but also an 
additional column next to CSS grade with name Description. I want to do this because I haev description available for
only few Letter's and I dont' want to show blank in the description field for other Letters. Please advise if that's possible
Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you want to add an extra column called description only if the column called CSS grade has letter A or searched for A. If so I would always have a description column in the table and hide it, than display it only when searched for A or if the grade column has A in it.

Comment: That's true. Do you think that it's doable in jQuery datatable?

Comment: It is certainly check out this link http://datatables.net/examples/api/show_hide.html

Comment: Mostly they have mentioned an example of user clicking a specific link for hiding a column. Did you find search based option anywhere?